# Matrix define works also with "==" operator, is it a bug?

Tags: stata

The syntax for matrix substitution is (`help matrix substitution`):

> matrix `A[r,c] = ...` where `r` and `c` are numeric scalar expressions.
>
> Description
>
> If the matrix expression to the right of the equal sign
> evaluates to a scalar or 1 x 1 matrix, the indicated element of `A` is
> replaced.[...]

and if I run (on Stata MP 14)

```
mat define A=(1,2,3,4)
matrix define A[1,2]=0
```

I obtain:

```
mat list A

A[1,4]
    c1  c2  c3  c4
r1   1   0   3   4
```

as expected.
However:

```
mat define B=(1,2,3,4)
matrix define B[1,2]==0
mat list B
B[1,4]
    c1  c2  c3  c4
r1   1   0   3   4
```

I did not expect this behavior because I am used to thinking `==` as a logical operator rather than an assignment operator. Can somebody explain to me why it happens? I cannot find any documentation about it.

Comment: I can confirm that this is still true in Stata 18 at the time of writing. It's a feature if you want Stata to indulge a typo and a bug if you think Stata should throw and error. I would raise this with StataCorp technical support.